# How to select population field from query in autopopulate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, auto-populate

I want to select population field from query but still I am getting all fields.Any way to achieve this?

```

```
Chat.find({ "bot_user": req.params.botuserId })
 .populate({
   path: 'bot_response',
   model: 'Child',
   select: 'plugin_id'
 })
 .exec((err,result) => {
  if (err) {
   res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
   deferred.reject(err)
  } else {
   res.json(result)
   deferred.resolve(result);
  }
})
```

```

Comment: `select: {'plugin_id':1}` have you tried this

Comment: It didn't work, still gettting all fields

Comment: post your both the collections and schema code

Comment: @Ashish can you follow this link :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716368/how-to-restrict-deep-population-in-mongoose-autopopulate It has more details