# How to restrict deep population in mongoose-autopopulate

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, auto-populate

I am using [mongoose-autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) npm package.
In one query I want to deep populate and in another query I want to populate till one level.
Here's my schema which is deep populating the data.

```
 ChildSchema = new Schema({
    plugin_id: { type: String }, 
    title: { type: String }, //card title
    text: { type: String },
    is_valid: { type: Boolean,require:true, default:  false},
    children: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child', autopopulate: true }]
});

ChildSchema.plugin(autopopulate);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Child', ChildSchema);
```

This is Chat History schema:

```
ChatHistorySchema = new Schema({
    type:{ type:Number }, 
    bot_response:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' } 
});
```

This is my query which in which I am trying to disable the auto-populate feature since I don't want deep population instead i want to populate Child schema only to 1 level.

```
    //query 
  ChatHistory.find({ "bot_user": req.params.botuserId }, {}, {autopopulate: false})
   .populate({
      path: 'bot_response',
      model: 'Child'
   })
   .exec((err,result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
      deferred.reject(err)
    } else {
      res.json(result)
      deferred.resolve(result);
    }
  })
```

This query is still returning deeply populated data.

I am not sure how can i get control over maxDepth from query.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you possibly think to look at the [Github repository](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate#it-can-limit-the-depth-using-maxdepth)? It's actually the very first thing that stands out to me on the page within the commit messages.

Comment: @NeilLunn edited my inputs above. I have already tried the maxDepth option. But it doesn't seem to fit in. 
Is there any way i can change maxDepth from a query ?